# flutter app crashed when using google sign in method

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m trying to use google sign in with my app but when i presses the google button the app crashes

if any one faced the same problem pls help I’m suffering
this is the code class

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;


  Future googleSignIn(context, {bool isLoading = true}) async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleAcount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleAcount != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleAcount.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        try {
          await authInstance.signInWithCredential(
            GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
              idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
              accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
            ),
          );
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => BtmNavBarScreen(),
            ),
          );
        } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
          Methods.ErrorDailog(subtitle: '${error.message}', context: context);

        } catch (error) {
          Methods.ErrorDailog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);

        } finally {}
      }
    }
  }

  notifyListeners();
}
```

and i think the problem is in here that i dont have the CFBundleURLTypes but i couldn’t know how to fix it
i didn’t know where to put the CFBundleURLTypes in the info.list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Shop App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>shop_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at this, everything which is marked you ahve to put in the `info.plist`:

```
<!-- Put me in the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file -->
<!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->
```

more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)